# How to stop objects moving to front when i group them? (illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

whenever i group object the group all moves to the front, which i do not want and it’s annoying to move them back every time. i’ve looked around a bit and i’ve tried looking it up, and i’m still not sure how to stop it. i’m new to illustrator.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's not possible. If you group objects, then everything in the group will be on the same layer. If you don't want to do this, then don't group them. You can select and move multiple objects together as one, without them being in a group.  BTW this goes for all vector software, not just Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. If you group a bunch of objects everyone gets lifted in the layering order so that the group contains members which are consequent in the layering order.

In the next image we have a line in the bottom and a star on the top:

[image]

If we group the line and the star the line is lifted up to the next from the star:

[image]

If we instead of it group the line and the ellipse we get this:

[image]

If we group the line and the rectangle the line will not get lifted because it's already the next from the rectangle.

The Layers panel is useful. Parts can be selected and moved there.

I had only one layer. Creating more layers doesn't help. A grouped object is moved to the same layer as the uppermost object in the group. The only possibility is to design the layering order so that nothing gets lifted.

In theory a part of an object could be hidden with a clipping- or opacity mask, but that makes things complex. I would at first try if I can plan the layering order.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Send the most recent object that you've created to the back and then try grouping them. I encountered this issue when trying to bulk group objects to one universal text object. Due to the text being created after each other object, once I tried to group them it pulled each object to front to match the text. Hope this helps